List smallest dates with criteria
I'm looking for to list specific rows from a table. A table on the worksheet is filled online with delivery orders. Another worksheet is then showing open deliveries after given times.
Two criteria:

rows state 'open'
later than given time on result sheet.

Showing results:
a) rows should be in order of date and time from the given time, the closest delivery to given time first.
b) result should show weekday, date, time and place.
c) time is shown without : -mark. E.g. 02:00 is shown as 0200.
Background

working on Microsoft Excel online version
working on Finnish location (date DD.MM.YYYY and 24 hours time format HH:MM)
how many deliveries is shown, should be defined easily
table of all deliveries has also other columns which are not shown on the result table.

Extra question if needed to solve at the same time:
Automatically add to the Weekday cell the weekday letters (Mon, Tue etc.) from the Date cell. For example, 27.10.2024 shows SUN.
E.g given time is 26.10.2024 18:28, the result:



Weekday
Date
Time
Place




SUN
27.10.2024
0200
home


SUN
27.10.2024
1600
work



Table of deliveries:



Weekday
Date
Time
State
Place
Name




FRI
25.10.2024
20:00
closed
home
Jack


SAT
26.10.2024
14:00
open
work
Ann


SUN
27.10.2024
02:00
open
home
Ann


SUN
27.10.2024
16:00
open
work
Jack



I have tried with functions MIN and SMALL with IF, AND and OR, but I can't find the solution. I would appreciate if someone would help me.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So why 2 results. Does the State matter? Should it be to a specific Name? Too many questions on the question itself. Please improve.

Thank you for attention. Sorry not to be clear. I tried to improve my question above. Only State and timing matters. Name and Place doesn't matter. Name is only to show that there are more columns at table that are not showed on result page.

I Name'd the table Deliveries
=CHOOSECOLS(
    VSTACK(
        Deliveries[#Headers],
        FILTER(
            Deliveries,
            ((Deliveries[Date] + Deliveries[Time]) >= givenTime) *
                (Deliveries[State] = "open")
        )
    ),
    1,
    2,
    3,
    5
)



Thank you for this short and brilliant answer. It works as needed. I little modified it. It shows the first 5 deliveries and if not any deliveries, shows N/A.
=IFERROR(CHOOSECOLS(VSTACK(Deliveries[#Headers],TAKE(FILTER(Deliveries,((Deliveries[Date] + Deliveries[Time]) >= givenTime) * (Deliveries[State] = "open")," "),5,5)),1,2,3,5),"N/A")

Using Orders as the name for the online table,
=LET(
    after, B8,
    columns_in_result, XMATCH(
        HSTACK(
            Orders[[#Headers],[Weekday]],
            Orders[[#Headers],[Date]],
            Orders[[#Headers],[Time]],
            Orders[[#Headers],[Place]]
        ),
        Orders[#Headers]
    ),
    deliveries_after, FILTER(
        CHOOSECOLS(Orders, columns_in_result),
        (Orders[Date] + Orders[Time] >= after) * (Orders[State] = "Open")
    ),
    sorted, SORTBY(
        deliveries_after,
        INDEX(deliveries_after, , 2) + INDEX(deliveries_after, , 3)
    ),
    VSTACK(
        CHOOSECOLS(Orders[#Headers], columns_in_result),
        HSTACK(
            CHOOSECOLS(sorted, 1),
            TEXT(CHOOSECOLS(sorted, 2), "dd.mm.yyyy"),
            TEXT(CHOOSECOLS(sorted, 3), "hhmm"),
            CHOOSECOLS(sorted, 4)
        )
    )
)


